# Got old Activity variables inside onDataReceived Java Android SerialPort

Tags: java, android, serial-port, serial-communication

I use serialportlib library from https://github.com/GeekBugs/Android-SerialPort/tree/master/serialportlib in Android project.

I have the two activities below:

- EventListActivity which redirects me to the second activity (ScanActivity) when I click an item from the list

```
@Override
    public void onEventClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("event",  events.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

- And ScanActivity, which receive the event sent from EventListActivity and where I open the SerialPort to receive data from qrCode scanned by external scanner

```
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String OPEN_SIGNAL = "AA5501F303";
    private static final String CLOSE_SIGNAL = "AA5501F305";
    private SerialPortHelper inputSerialPortHelper;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    private Event event;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        event = (Event) getIntent().getExtras().get("event");
        this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(event.getTitle());
        openScannerPort();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(inputSerialPortHelper != null) inputSerialPortHelper.close();
        getIntent().removeExtra("event");
        inputSerialPortHelper.setISerialPortDataListener(null);
        finish();
    }

    private void openScannerPort() {
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        inputSerialPortHelper = new SerialPortHelper();
        openPort(inputSerialPortHelper, BAUDRATE.getBaudrate(BAUDRATE.B115200));
        if (!inputSerialPortHelper.isOpen()) inputSerialPortHelper.open();
        inputSerialPortHelper.setISerialPortDataListener(new ISerialPortDataListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(byte[] bytes) {
                // process the received bytes
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataSend(byte[] bytes) {
                Log.i("data sent input", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The scenario is:

- Launching the application and I see the list of event
- I select an event and see the ScanActivity
- When I scan a qrCode on the Scanner, the code inside the "onDataReceived" is executed and everything is fine till then
- When I go back to the EventList and select another event, in the onCreate function I get the selected event information, but when I scan and inside the onDataReceived, I still get the previously selected event information

Why do I still have the previous variable inside the onDataReceived?

Comment: What is the launchMode of the ScanActivity? Also getIntent().removeExtra("event"); AFAIK this doesn't work.

Comment: @TheLibrarian The actual launchMode is the default (standard)